# How to remove broken characters present in ISO encoded XML file

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-16, iso-8859-1

When I tried to convert the xml file with a UTF-16 encoding to ISO-8859-1, I am seeing broken characters like `Â`.

Can you please suggest some solution to remove the broken characters? I want the XML in an ISO encoded format.

Here is my code,

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SqlConn")))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = commandText;
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

        // the data from database data is UTF encoded
        using (StreamWriter textwriterISO = new StreamWriter(path + "_out.XML", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
        {                                  
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            Console.WriteLine("Writing results.This could take a very long time.");
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sqlDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(sqlDataReader[i].ToString());
                    string ascii = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(arr);
                    textwriter.WriteLine(sqlDataReader.GetName(i),ascii));
                }

                textwriter.Flush();
            }
        }
    }                         
}
```

Comment: Could we trouble you for some of the code you're using? We don't even know what programming language you're using.

Comment: @JLRishe, I am using C# language for conversion

Comment: And would you mind showing us your code, or do you want us to do all the work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is misusing the `StreamWriter` class and doing the wrong kind of manual encoding of the DB data.  You are converting the source UTF-16 DB data to CP28591, interpretting the CP28591 bytes as UTF-8 in order to convert them back to UTF-16, then having `StreamWriter` convert the now-malformed UTF-16 to ISO-8859-1 when writing to the file.  That is the completely wrong thing to do, let alone the wasted overhead of all those conversions.  Let `StreamWriter` handle the encoding of the source UTF-16 DB data directly, get rid of everything else, eg:

```
using (StreamWriter textwriterISO = new StreamWriter(path + "_out.XML", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{                                  
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    Console.WriteLine("Writing results.This could take a very long time.");
    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sqlDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            // you were originally calling the WriteLine(String, Object) overload.
            // Are you sure you want to call that? It interprets the first parameter
            // as a pattern to format the value of the second parameter. A DB column
            // name is not a formatting pattern!
            textwriterISO.WriteLine(sqlDataReader.GetName(i), sqlDataReader[i].ToString());

            // perhaps you meant to write the DB column name and field value separately?
            //
            // textwriterISO.WriteLine(sqlDataReader.GetName(i));
            // textwriterISO.WriteLine(sqlDataReader[i].ToString());
        }
        textwriterISO.Flush();
    }
}
```

With that said, you mention that you want the output in XML format.  `StreamWriter` by itself is not going to output XML for you.  Use the `XmlSerializer` or `XmlTextWriter` class instead to convert your DataReader data into XML that is then written to your `StreamWriter`.

Comment: What encoding is used by the `sqlDataReader[i]`? Is `textwriterISO` supposed to be the same as `textwriter`?

Comment: `sqlDataReader[i]` returns an `Object` that represents the DB data, whatever it uses. The `ToString()` converts that data to a UTF-16 string, however the DB needs to do that conversion. And yes, `textwriter` and `textwriterISO` were supposed to be the same thing.